# PinGuyOS (Ubuntu derived) Eclipse won't start after install, error code 1

Tags: java, eclipse

So I can't get Eclipse to start after installing in on the latest version of PinGuyOS in a VirtualBox. Here's the error box I get:
[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSMyS.png)

My eclipse.ini is the following:

```
  1 -startup
  2 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
  3 --launcher.library
  4 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.dist
  5 -showsplash
  6 org.eclipse.platform
  7 --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
  8 256m                                                                        
  9 --launcher.defaultAction
 10 openFile
 11 -vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java
 12 -vmargs
 13 -Xms40m
 14 -Xmx384m
 15 -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
```

Without the line numbers. I put the vm line in because it wasn't working prior, but I'm still not able to run Eclipse. Assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the java version

```
   sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: Changing my java version to 7 worked! I guess Eclipse might not be compatible with Java 9 yet. Thank you!